# JQuery and Vuejs APIs not passing nor retrieving data to database Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, api, vue.js

I had working been on a web app using Django and had to take a 3-month break. I decided to continue and suddenly all my jquery and vuejs code is not working although it had been perfectly working 3-months ago. (And perhaps I could have made a last minute change before going for my break that affected the JS before I went on my break)

This is my base.html

```
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- Vue Js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <!-- JQuery script -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

urls.py

```
from conversation.api import api_add_message
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/add_message/', api_add_message, name='api_add_message'),
   ]
```

api.py

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import ConversationMessage

@login_required
def api_add_message(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    content = data['content']
    conversation_id = data['conversation_id']

    message = ConversationMessage.objects.create(conversation_id=conversation_id, content=content, created_by=request.user)
```

template.html

```
<li class="chat-left" v-for="message in messages">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
      <img  :src="message.image"alt="Retail Admin">
          <div class="chat-name">[[ message.user ]]</div>
       </div>
     <div class="chat-text">[[ message.content ]]</div>
     <div class="chat-hour">[[ message.user ]]</div>
</li>
```

And this is my script in the template

```
{% block script %}
<script>
    var conversationapp = new Vue({
        el: '#conversationapp',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data () {
            return {
                messages: [],
                content: '',
                user: '{{ request.user.username }}',
                created_at: 'Now',
                image: '{% if request.user.profile.image %}{{ request.user.profile.image.url }}{% endif %}'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitMessage() {
                if (this.content.length > 0) {
                    var message = {
                        'content': this.content,
                        'user': this.user,
                        'created_at': this.created_at,
                        'image': this.image,
                        'conversation_id': '{{ conversation.id }}'
                    };

                    this.messages.unshift(message);

                    fetch('/api/add_message/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        credentials: 'same-origin',
                        body: JSON.stringify(message)
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })

                    this.content = '';
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

After rendering the template, instead of retrieving data to replace in the [[]] braces it simply shows the braces as is. And when I want to pass data to the database it does not do so.

This is a sample of one of the JS scripts in my project, however, all the JS in the project is not working. The only error my console is detecting is a CORS error, in which I am not requesting data from another domain. I assume I am getting this error only because I am using icons from fontawesome CDN. And when I run the vuejs devtools for the vuejs scripts, it is not detecting any vuejs components although vuejs scripts are being loaded to the site.

Considering that it had been working I don't know where to begin trouble shooting, nor what area of code I should display here to better increase my chances of being helped. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use {{field_name}} instead of [].
and in django api should always return response make sure you api return response
like

```
return render(request, 'template_name.html', context={'message': message})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you well, but I have delimiters in place for that. And I did return the response in the views.py, I happen to not have shown that part of the code.

Comment: i mean change [[ message.user ]] to {{ message.user }} and so on

Comment: should be 
`<li class="chat-left" v-for="message in messages">
   <div class="chat-avatar">
      <img  :src="message.image"alt="Retail Admin">
          <div class="chat-name">{{ message.user}}</div>
       </div>
     <div class="chat-text">{{ message.content }}</div>
     <div class="chat-hour">{{ message.user }}</div>
</li>`

Comment: I have now tried it, it did not work

Comment: you can get post data using request.POST.